# Is it possible to use ts-morph in eslint?

Tags: typescript, eslint, ts-morph

I want to use `ts-morph` in eslint.

I ask that because I see when I create a plugin for eslint, eslint runs through all my files in my project each time. I mean when I have a `Program` selector then it invokes many times per my files.

So when I want to use `ts-morph` it just happens once. load the project and I have many functions and type-checking through all my project files.

Is it possible to pass the ts-morph `project` object to all eslint plugins? so I can have the project variable in my eslint function?